# How do I count how many times a value repeats in a CSV file on python?

Tags: python

I have a csv file with a musicians ssn and the albums they've written, I need to count how many albums each musician has written

The CSV file looks like this:

```
100000000,7
100000000,21
100000000,24
100000001,5
100000001,7
100000001,16
100000002,9
100000002,14
100000002,15
100000002,21
100000003,2
100000003,8
100000003,10
100000003,14
100000003,15
100000003,19
```

My code needs to output something like this:

```
100000000 no of albums = 3
100000001 no of albums = 3
100000002 no of albums = 4
100000003 no of albums = 6
```

Comment: Please post the work you've done so far. The csv module and collections.defaultdict would likely help.

Comment: read the file, parse the item, keep a running count

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    count = dict()
    for line in f.readlines():
        artist = line.split(",")[0]
        if artist in count.keys():
            count[artist] += 1
        else:
            count[artist] = 1
    print(count)
```

This is a simple code snippet that will do the work. It is not the most elegant but you'll get the logic.

Comment: I could not find the necessary tutorial on my class or online, sorry if it seems that way, also this is a small part and I did try multiple other methods but it did not give me the desired result, thanks for your help